# display bar chart with timeseries data

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to display data, time based, here is a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/9fgrf31b/

I think that the problem is located here :

```
const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: res_data,
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'day'
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
        },
      }],
    },
  },
})
```

As you can see this is quiet ugly. The problem is that I can't put a global label because date may not be consistent. I tried with several options (distribution series/linear, etc...) as point out in the doc : http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#scale-distribution but this obviously not working correctly